# Determining what side of a plane a point is on

Tags: linear-algebra

I've run into an interesting piece of legacy code that I'm having trouble understanding.

We perform two rotations using euler matrices and then multiply by the original vector to determine the new position of a point (x,y).  No problem.

However, the next line of code takes the dot product of the rotation matrix 2nd row with the vector to determine which side of the plane the point is on.    For clarity,  the rotation matrix is the product of a rotation around the x axis then around the y axis, a “combo” matrix.

I'm aware of how to do this using the dot product of a plane and a vector,  but I can find no references about why using the 2nd row of a euler matrix works -- and it does work!

Thank you

Comment: This question is probably better suited to math.stack.exchange.

Comment: In your question you mention "the plane". What plane is it?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a basic rotation:

```
[p0]   [R00 R01 R02] [q0]
[p1] = [R10 R11 R12] [q1]
[p2]   [R20 R21 R22] [q2]
```

The "y" component of p (p1) is just the dot product between the 2nd row of R with q. If positive, it's on one side of the x-z plane, and if negative, it's on the other. If it's zero, it sitting right on top of the plane. (Recall that the x-z plane contain all of the points where y is 0.)